# Behavior of super with same method in two hierarchies

Tags: scala

Having this traits and classes:

```
 trait A {
    def print() {
      println("A")
    }
  }

  trait B extends A {
    override def print() {
      println("B")
      super.print()
    }
  }
  trait C extends A {
    override def print() {
      println("C")
      super.print()
    }
  }

  class H {
    def print() {
      println("H")
    }
  }

  class X extends H with B with C {
    override def print() {
      println("X"); super.print()
    }
  }
```

And calling print from an X object:

```
  val x = new X                                   
  x.print
```

The printing I get is:

```
X
C
B
A
```

Is there a way to reach at some point the print method in `H class` starting from the print method in `X class`?

I see traits A, B and C belong to one hierarchy and H is in another hierarchy. In both hierarchies, we have the print method. Having `class X` extending both hierarchies, I think there must be a way to reach the print method from `class H` too. After all, `class X` is defined as "class X extends H....".

I think I'm missing something important here; I guess I'm not quite understanding it.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `super[H].print()`.

You can find answers/google linearization to see the hierarchy after mixins.

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html

Comment: Thank you. That works fine. Yeah, I read about linearization and, to my understanding, applying it I got the hierarchy "H - A - B - C - X". My confusion was about having two hierarchies and overriding the same method. A curiosity: even when using an X as an H, I get the same printing `val h: H = new X; h.print` (I know the relationship is built at compile time and if calling H.print is desired, it should be a concern of the X class definition and not a duty of the runtime). Do you know if it's possible to override in class X "print" methods separately??? (the print from H and the print from C)

Comment: There are techniques (or tricks) to disambiguate the signatures, but otherwise, this is what overriding a method means.